# Private key encryption in .NET 4.0 of a very large number

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, elliptic-curve

In my scenario, I would like to encrypt a very big  number (10^27) using a private key and later be able to decrypt it using a public key. The problem I have is that I want to keep the size of the encrypted text as small as possible.

I know that .NET has support for public key encryption (RSACryptoServiceProvider), but the encrypted text gets so huge.

Would it work to instead  treat the private key as a public key?

Would Elliptic curve cryptography produce a smaller output?

Comment: [System.Numerics.BigInteger.ToByteArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Is the encrypted text the very big number, or something else? The result of an RSA encryption - or decryption in your case? have you got public and private mixed up, or is this a signature? - is going be a number between 0 and the modulus and likely will have no obvious redundancy and so will not be compressible. I don't think ECC or DSA will make any difference: it'll be the same situation. And any good symmetrically-encrypted data is indistinguishable from random data and so not compressible either: you'd have to compress before encrypting.

Comment: @Rup, the 'big number' is what I want to encrypt!

Comment: @Rup The first part of the comment makes sense. ECC uses much lower key sizes so the difference would be rather large. Nobody was talking about compression neither.

Comment: @Artem, use the @<name> to make sure Rup is notified about the comment... Please indicate if you just want to achieve confidentiality with the given code or if you want to do achieve authentication and suchlike.

Comment: @owlstead Fair enough - I'd missed that 10^27 was relatively small compared to any of these's keys (which is obvious in hindsight). I just assumed compression was on the table to get a smaller output.

Comment: @owlstead, The most important thing is to make it almost impossible to encrypt. The 'big number' is a key that should only be encrypted in one secret software, while it can always be decrypted by anyone who has the public software.

Comment: If it can always be decrypted by public software then this sounds more like a authentication token to me. As anyone can decrypt, you don't seem to require confidentiality but non-repudiation. In that case send the public number in plain and send a signature with it. If you use ECDSA you will get better size signatures. You could also use the retracted ISO 9796 (~RSA) signatures, but those have largely be broken so you should know how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to achieve confidentiality you should always encrypt with the public key, not the private key. RSA encryption is not defined for encryption with the private key, and the results may vary (especially the kind of padding that is applied).

For direct RSA encryption, the size of the encrypted message is identical to the modulus. Now the modulus should be at least 2048 bits by now, and your message is only about (27/3)*10=90 bits. So RSA would have a large overhead, independent on the key used. Using ECIES is therefore likely to give significant benefits.